# How to export .org file to markdown with title, author, tags, etc... information included?

Tags: org-mode, markdown

I'd like to use org-mode to create blog posts which are to published on GitHub Pages.
I found a repository with a nice [stencil](https://github.com/cissic/peterroelants.github.io) with tags and search option and I would like just to use it.
However, the posts in this stencil are written in markdown files, where properties of the post are coded at the beginning of the file like this:

```
layout: post_markdown
title: This is the post title
description: Here goes description.
tags:
- Jekyll
- GitHub
- org-mode
---
```

I'm using org-md-export-as-markdown command to export my post written as an .org file
where .org file has the header section included:

```
#+TITLE: This is the post title 
#+AUTHOR: author name
#+DATE: <2022-09-08 czw>
#+KEY: Jekyll, GitHub, org-mod
```

Unfortunately, Emacs exports none of those properties to the markdown file.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried [pandoc-mode](https://github.com/joostkremers/pandoc-mode)?

Comment: No I haven't. However I used pandoc itself with no success. But your comment encouraged me to give pandoc a try once again and now I know what I did wrong. I forgot to add `-s` parameter and I kept getting markdown file with just a fragment of code. Running `pandoc -s file.org -o file.md` creates a file with front matter included. Thank you.

Comment: Good. Pandoc-mode is a nice frontend that makes the usage of pandoc easier.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [ox-hugo](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/ox-hugo).